# what is going on here?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

Suppose we have a function $f(x), D:( -\infty,0)\cup (0,\infty)$ and for which $$f'(x) = \frac{x^3-1}{x^3} $$

Apparently there is only one point of extremum here, $x=1$, however upon reviewing the textbook $x=0$ also appears as an extremum even though its not in $D$...this leads to a false graph representation and plenty of other unwanted things, so the question is..why?

Comment: How can there be an extremum of $f$ at $x=0$ when $0$ is not in the domain of $f$?

Comment: thing is $x=0 $ is still some sort of extremum even though  its not in the domain

Comment: I would say that an extremum can only occur at a point of the domain.  The function needs to be defined at a (domain) value in order to have an extremum at that value.

Comment: thing is it does increase at $x<0$ and decreases at $0<x<1$

Comment: so it $(x=0)$ does serve as an extremum even though not in $D$

Comment: This strikes me as unconventional (to allow for an extreme value to occur at a point not in the domain).

Comment: If you look at your definition of what an extremum is you will find that you need the point in the domain.

Answer (score 5):

You can integrate the function to get $$f(x)=\begin {cases}x+\frac 1{2x^2}+c_1&x \lt 0 \\x+\frac 1{2x^2}+c_2&x \gt 0 \end {cases}$$  Note that the constants of integration may be different on the two sections of the domain.  You have a minimum (not maximum) at $x=1$  The function blows up to $+\infty$ approaching $0$ from either side, which may be what makes you think it has an extremum there, but it does not.  What value would the extremum have?